# How can I use netty to build reliable UDP?

Tags: udp, netty

How can I use netty to build reliable UDP?

Modify netty's source code?
Or use netty as low level, and implement reliable at the application layer?

Thank you!
Best Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your application's design. It is much easier to build a thin application layer (with simple data frame with sequence numbering, acknowledgement frame with received sequence number, and optional timer handlers to implement re-transmission) than modifying the Netty UDP transport source to add these things.

This approach might face some issues like, sending frames bigger thank IP frames, you have handle application PDU fragmentation, later you might have to keep adding more things to the layer. Any way I would do this only if TCP or SCTP (Netty 4.X supports SCTP) can not be used for the purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I want to build a fps game server that requires high time performances.So I think TCP SCTP is not so suitable.I have tested netty that it can send/receive 64KB packages, so I don't think that I should care IP frames.